# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE can't update same row twice

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to use sql in Mysql

```
INSERT INTO product_sales (product_code,product_desc,product_quantity,product_sales,product_group,insert_time) 
VALUES ('ZSHA','AAA','1','1.55','TESTING','$TEST time')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    product_quantity = VALUES(product_quantity) + '123',
    product_sales = VALUES(product_sales) + '1.5',
    product_desc = 'hello',
    insert_time = 'hello';
```

Here is my Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_sales` (
    `product_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `product_desc` longtext,
    `product_quantity` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_sales` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_group` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `insert_time` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_code`,`product_group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the description of the table

`| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_code     | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| product_desc     | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product_quantity | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product_sales    | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product_group    | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| insert_time      | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |`

Here is the problem, after i inserted the row, this query only update the data once in the database which means after the very first time update, the data won't update anymore?

What is the problem of this sql?

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving? Try to not "quote" numeric values: `... product_quantity =VALUES(product_quantity) + 123 ...`

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately it is still not working in this way

Comment: everything works fine from my side - no matter whether numeric values are quoted or not? Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: I have use the same sql on my end and it is not working

Comment: "is not working" doesn't describe the observed behavior. The behavior we expect is successful execution of the statement (no errors, no warnings) and MySQL reporting "0 row(s) affected". That's the behavior we expect to observe, and we wouldn't describe that behavior as "is not working".  It's not at all clear what behavior is actually being observed. And it's not at all clear what behavior is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine. There doesn't seem to be any problem with the SQL; it seems to be performing the specified operations; the behavior we observe is exactly as described in the documentation MySQL Reference Manual.

On the third execution, there are no changes to be applied; the resulting row will match exactly the row that is already stored. So MySQL reports `0 row(s) affected`, and the row remains unchanged.

After first execution:

```
product_code product_desc product_quantity product_sales product_group insert_time  
------------ ------------ ---------------- ------------- ------------- ----------
ZSHA         AAA                         1          1.55 TESTING       $TEST time
```

After second execution:

```
------------ ------------ ---------------- ------------- ------------- ----------
ZSHA         hello                     124          3.05 TESTING       hello
```

After third execution (and fourth, fifth, ...):

```
------------ ------------ ---------------- ------------- ------------- ----------
ZSHA         hello                     124          3.05 TESTING       hello
```

These results are exactly as we would expect. It's not at all clear why would expect something different. (Maybe we're not understanding what the special `VALUES()` function does?)

---

The question leaves us guessing... what behavior is being observed, and what behavior is expected. Saying that it "is not working" is next to useless, in terms of explanation.

If we want to add the value supplied in the VALUES clause to the existing value in the column...

```
INSERT INTO ... ( ... , product_quantity , ... )
VALUES ( ... , '1' , ... )
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE product_quantity = IFNULL(product_quantity,0) + VALUES(product_quantity)
```

When a duplicate key exception occurs, this will get the current value of the `product_quantity` column from the row.  If it's null, we return 0 otherwise we return the value stored in the row. Then add to that the value supplied in the INSERT statement for product_quantity.

If we don't want a NULL value to overwrite the current value in the column, we can wrap that in an IFNULL or COALESCE as well

```
... 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE product_quantity = IFNULL(product_quantity,0) + IFNULL(VALUES(product_quantity),0)
```

We're guessing at the specification; guessing at what the SQL is supposed to do, what behavior we want to achieve. Without that, we're just flinging "try this" SQL without anyway of determining if the proposed SQL satisfies the specification.

Comment: I'm expecting to keep adding up the value on product quantity and product_sales, am i miss understand this sql??

Comment: when you enter the same sql again, the values is not adding up again

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you have to do your insert statement if you want to keep adding values to columns **product_quantity** and **product_sales**, first remove **VALUES()** method, and second (maybe optional) for skip auto cast of types on engines, use integers and float numbers on the **SUM**.

```
INSERT INTO product_sales (product_code,product_desc,product_quantity,product_sales,product_group,insert_time) 
VALUES ('ZSHA','AAA','1','1.55','TESTING','$TEST time')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    product_quantity = product_quantity + 123,
    product_sales = product_sales + 1.5,
    product_desc = 'hello',
    insert_time = 'hello';
```

I let you a description of the meaning of VALUES() method next, since i think you misunderstand it:

**VALUES() Explained:**

In an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts.

Comment: it seems odd (unreasonably so) to add a constant value of 123 to product quantity.  the more typical use case would add the new value to the existing value in the column.  but we're really just guessing, without a specification.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but looking at all the "testing" words around the example, i took like it was that, just a test example.

Comment: Without a specification, without understanding what OP is trying to achieve, I wouldn't post an answer that says "**This is the way you have to ...**", not  without an understanding what OP is trying to achieve, or at least a description of what the example code is designed to do.

Comment: But, i posted my answer after reading his comment: _"I'm expecting to keep adding up the value on product quantity and product_sales"_. I was not guessing anything... Anyway, if my answer bother you, tellme and i will just delete it.